# Why this piece of code does not work in perl...Its simple

Tags: perl

```
#!usr/bin/perl
$file_name = "file.txt";
open(FILE,$file_name);
while(<FILE>)
{
my $line = $_;
if($line =~ m/Svr\b/)
{
my $server_name;
$server_name  = $1;
print $server_name;
}
}
```

---

file.txt:

```
 ewrerfSvr//To be extracted
 Rate=rpm
 ID=123
 RATE=45
 ADDR=retriveBal
 Grocer="-r -e ${MAIN_ROOT}/logs/stderr -o ${MAIN_ROOT}/logs/stdout -A --"
freedonSvr
 BALFSvr   //to be extracted
 Rate=rpm1
 ID=12323
 RATE=45etf
 ADDR=retriveBal
 Grocer="-r -e ${MAIN_ROOT}/logs/stderr -o ${MAIN_ROOT}/logs/stdout -A --"
freedonSvr -D ${REV_AccountBalance_NAME}"//
```

Also I want to  extract:

```
 REV_AccountBalance
```

Give me suggestion to do this using regular expression.

Comment: I'd suggest indenting your code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file_name = "file.txt";
open(my $fh,$file_name) or die "Could not open file";

while(<$fh>) {
    if (m/(\w*Svr)\b/) { print "$1\n"; }
}
```

You should get used to using `warnings` and `strict` and trapping errors from calls like `open`.

And specifically in answer to your question, you need to use brackets within your regexp to extract into the `$N` variables.

Comment: 'In the United States, "bracket" usually refers specifically to the "square" or "box" type; in British usage, it normally refers to a parenthesis mark.' - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket.  The unqualified term "bracket" is hence best avoided.

Answer (score 2):

`$1` will get you the part of the matched string in capturing parentheses, but you don't have those.  Did you mean your regex to be `m/Svr\b(.+)/` ?  Please show the output you are wanting to get; the comments in file.txt aren't explicit enough.

Comment: (m/(\w*Svr)\b/)....works well
($line =~ m/Svr\b/) ----chose by me does not work..
Whats the bigg diff..Why mine is wrong

Comment: @Sreeja: yours doesn't have the () that show what to put in $1